# How to reuse a simple dense Tensorflow graph in a program?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am pretty new to Tensorflow,and was trying to find out a way of saving and restoring a dense layer using simple programs. I used the following simple program to initialise and save the graph.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import os

import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[1], [2], [3], [4]], dtype=tf.float32,name = "x" )
y_true = tf.constant([[0], [-1], [-2], [-3]], dtype=tf.float32, name = "y_t")

linear_model = tf.layers.Dense(units=1, name = "sutej")

y_pred = linear_model(x)
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y_true, predictions=y_pred)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
  _, loss_value = sess.run((train, loss))
  print(loss_value)

all_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)
print(all_vars)
for v in all_vars:
    v_ = sess.run(v)
    print(v_)

print(sess.run(y_pred))

saver = tf.train.Saver()

saver.save(sess, '/home/sutej/Tensorflow/newsave/newsave',global_step=1000)
```

And the following code to restore the graph

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import os

import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/home/sutej/Tensorflow/newsave/newsave-1000.meta')
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/home/sutej/Tensorflow/newsave/'))

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
x=graph.get_tensor_by_name('x:0')
y_true=graph.get_tensor_by_name('y_t:0')

graph = tf.get_default_graph()

all_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)
print(all_vars)
for v in all_vars:
    v_ = sess.run(v)
    print(v_)

print(sess.run('sutej/kernel:0'))


print(sess.run(tf.layers.dense(inputs=x,units=1,name = 'sutej', reuse=True)))
```

In the output I am able to see that the graph has been restored and so have the constants, biases and weights from the saved file. But when I try to pass the inputs through the dense layer (last line of my restore code) I am getting an error. The output log is as follows.

```
[<tf.Variable 'sutej/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'sutej/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>]
[[-0.98440635]]
[0.95415276]
[[-0.98440635]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load_saver.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(sess.run(tf.layers.dense(inputs=x,units=1,name = 'sutej', reuse=True)))
  File "/home/sutej/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py", line 253, in dense
    return layer.apply(inputs)
  File "/home/sutej/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 828, in apply
    return self.__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sutej/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 699, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes)
  File "/home/sutej/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py", line 138, in build
    trainable=True)
  File "/home/sutej/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 546, in add_variable
    partitioner=partitioner)
  File "/home/sutej/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable.py", line 436, in _add_variable_with_custom_getter
    **kwargs_for_getter)
  File "/home/sutej/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1317, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/sutej/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1079, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/sutej/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 425, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/sutej/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 394, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource, constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/sutej/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 751, in _get_single_variable
    "reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?" % name)
ValueError: Variable sutej/kernel does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
```

What is that I am getting wrong? And how can I work around that? I do not want to manually multiply the kernel and add the bias, but I am looking for something more elegant like `print(sess.run(y_pred))` in the first part of the code.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that you want - `print(sess.run(y_pred))` - is exactly what you should do after restore. You imported the graph and restored the variables. The TensorFlow world is pretty much in the same state as what you had in your training script. You can run the graph the same way you run it in the training script.

To advance your understanding a bit. Calling `tf.layers.dense` creates the variables and operations (represented as nodes in the graph). You called it in your training script for this reason. When you imported the graph and restored variable values, you created the variables and operations. Calling `tf.layers.dense` again makes little sense.

When you tried calling `sess.run()` with a string, it did not work because you need to pass in a tensor object. There are several ways to get the tensors you want:

- Using `get_tensor_by_name` as you did. This is a little brittle because tensor names can change as you work on your model.
- You can add your tensors to a `collection` before saving the graph and retrieve them from this collection when restoring. The collection name should be more stable than the tensor name.
- If you have the code that builds the graph (i.e. your training script). You can use that code to recreate the same graph. Then, you would have the same python object `y_pred` you had during training. You would need to make a change to your restoring script in this case. Since you created the graph using your code, you don't need to `import_meta_graph_def`. You just need to restore variable values.

Comment: I tried calling the `tf.layers.dense` again as the line `print(sess.run(y_pred))` throws the following error  
`NameError: name 'y_pred' is not defined`

Comment: @sutejkulgod, Your questions seems to imply that you are still confused but I can't figure out about what exactly. Can you update the question with exact code you are running and a full stack trace of the error?

Comment: yeah, I am still confused about it, and the full code and stack trace are already in the question. You can use the same code, by changing the save and load location to replicate the problem if needed. Thanks.

Comment: To be very explicit, you can do `sess.run(y_true)` after you got the tensor with `y_true=graph.get_tensor_by_name('y_t:0')`. This is the first way I described above.

Comment: Yeah I can do `sess.run(y_true)`  and I will get the required result. But I am facing issue while trying to do `sess.run(y_pred)` as I cant restore it using the tensor name like I can for y_t.

Comment: The operation `sutej/BiasAdd` seems to be the last operation which leads to the output so running `sess.run('sutej/BiasAdd:0')` gives me the output which corresponds to `sess.run(y_pred)` in the first program.

Comment: I am glad that you found a solution. As I mentioned, getting tensors by name is quite brittle. If possible, I would suggest using one of the other two approaches.